# is the sum $\sum_{t=1}^T {\beta_t^2 \over \alpha_t} \ge 1$

Tags: inequality

Is the sum $$\sum_{t=1}^T {\beta_t^2 \over \alpha_t} \ge 1$$ given that $$\sum_{t=1}^T \alpha_t = \sum_{t=1}^T \beta_t = 1$$ (where $T \in \mathbb{N}$)?

I'm not sure how I can prove this.

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha_t,\beta_t\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a counterexample:
$\alpha_1=-1,\alpha_2=2,\beta_1=2,\beta_2=-1$.

So I assume $\alpha_t,\beta_t\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

By Cauchy-Schwartz inequality,

$$\bigg( \frac{\beta_1^2}{\alpha_1}+\frac{\beta_2^2}{\alpha_2}+\cdots+\frac{\beta_T^2}{\alpha_T} \bigg)(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_T) \ge (\beta_1+\beta_2+\cdots+\beta_T)^2$$
$$\implies \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{\beta_t^2}{\alpha_t} \ge1$$

Comment: didn't know I could use Cauchy-Schwartz for this! In fact, there's a name for this: Sedrakyan's lemma. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if $\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}>0,\forall i$.use $AM-GM$ inequality
$$\dfrac{\beta^2_{i}}{\alpha_{i}}+\alpha_{i}\ge 2\beta_{i}$$
sum this $i=1,2,\cdots,T$

Comment: this is a nice answer, thank you!